# Getting information from nested div and class in HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get to the div class="article" nested inside a div called div id="tabs=main from this a HTML-page that looks like this:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g7FY58hZ)

I have tried something like this but with no result:

```
var targetAbs = doc.querySelectorAll("article");
```

Anyone have any tips for me? Not even sure I'm suppose to use this queryselector. I have also tried the getElementsByClassName, but I think since it's nested I can reach it.

Answer (score 2):

`doc` isn't a standard variable provided by the browser. You are looking for `document`.

Class selectors begin with a `.`. `"article"` is a type selector and will match `<article>` elements.

Comment: Okay, but in my program document has been declared as doc. That's why I'm writing doc.

I don't understand what you mean with the last part. I'm looking for the class="article" inside the div="tabs-main", or atleast I think it's inside that div.
Should I not use the queryselector you mean or?

Comment: @anderssinho — You need to put a `.` at the front of your selector to turn it into a class selector.

Answer (score 1):

As your element has a class of `article`, you need to use the following code:

```
doc.querySelectorAll(".article");
```

You need to place a `.` in front of the selector when it is referring to a class.

Comment: Okay, is it just going to look for a class that is called "article" or will it also find a class that is called "article-info cf"?
And if it does just return the article class just, how can I extract the information and put it in a string?Because I guess I don't just get the content back but just the element itself or? It's really that I'm after. 
How do I make it to a string?

Comment: No, it will not match a class called `article-info cf` (this is two different classes as there is a space: it has the class `article-info` and the class `cf`). To get the text from the element, you need to do `doc.querySelector(".article").innerHTML`. The reason I used `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll` is because we only want a single `article` element.

Comment: Okay good to know!
If I now use the innerHTML on the querySelector and store it on a variable like:

var targetAbs = doc.querySelectorAll(".article").innerHTML;

Will that variable hold all the information?

Comment: Yes, that should hold all the information if there is only one element with a class of `article` in the scope - if not, you'll need to be more specific with your selector scope!

Comment: How can I be more specific with my scope in the selector? I tested my program now and I don't get anything in my variable :/

Comment: You should use the following code, with `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll`: `var targetAbs = doc.querySelector(".article").innerHTML;`

Comment: Okay will try that. What is the diffrence btw?

Comment: `querySelector` gets a single element from the page to match the selector (`.article`). `querySelectorAll` gets every selector which matches the selector. If you only want to select one element (which you do here) then you use `querySelector`.

Comment: If I still get nothing back, what can it depend on?
I get an error-message that says: "TypeError: doc.querySelector(..) is null
I'm using this bit of code in a scraper, don't know if that helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93615/discussion-between-anderssinho-and-james-monger).